# If F is real-entire, then how to write, $F(z)- F(w)$ in terms of $(z-w)$ and $(\bar{z}- \bar{w})$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, proof-verification

Define $F:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ such that $F(z)= \sum_{j,k=0}^{\infty}c_{j,k} z^{j} \bar{z}^{k}$ is an entire real analytic function on $\mathbb C$ with $F(0)=0.$

> **My question is** :How to show:
>   $$F(z)- F(w)= (z-w) \sum_{j,k,l,m \geq 0} c_{j,k, l,m} z^{j} \bar{z}^{k} w^{l}\bar{w}^{m} + (\bar{z}- \bar{w})\sum_{j,k,l,m \geq 0} c'_{j,k, l,m} z^{j} \bar{z}^{k}w^{l}\bar{w}^{m}  ?$$

[The paper I have been reading gives hint:  $F(z)- F(w)= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{d}{dt} (F(tz+(1-t)w)) dt$; I don't see, how  this relation is useful to verify above relation]

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It may be more transparent without introducing $t$. Begin with
$$F(w+\zeta) = \sum_{j,k}c_{j,k} (w+\zeta)^j(\bar w +\bar \zeta)^k \tag{1}$$
Use the binomial formula: $(w+\zeta)^j = \sum_{l=0}^j \binom{j}{l} w^{j-l} \zeta^l$ and similarly for the other factor. This gives
$$F(w+\zeta)= \sum_{j,k,l,m}b_{j,k,l,m} w^{j-l} \zeta^l \bar w^{k-m} \bar \zeta^m \tag{2}$$
If we temporarily set $\zeta=0$ in (2), only the terms with $l=m=0$ remain. Therefore, by subtracting $F(w)$ we cancel them out, arriving at
$$F(w+\zeta) - F(w)= \sum_{\substack{j,k,l,m \\ l+m>0}} b_{j,k,l,m} w^{j-l} \zeta^l \bar w^{k-m} \bar \zeta^m \tag{3}$$
The sum in (3) can be split into two: those with $l>0$ (they have common factor $\zeta$) and the rest (which have common factor $\bar \zeta$). Set $\zeta = z-w$ to get the desired expansion.